# generator of a subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

How many subgroups does $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$ have?
List a generator for each of these subgroups?

By the fundamental theorem of Cyclic group:

The subgroup of the the Cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$ are $\left \langle a^\frac{n}{k} \right \rangle$ for all divisor k of n

The divisor k of $n=20$ are$ k=1,2,4,5,10,20$

So, the subgroups are $\left \langle a^{1} \right \rangle$,$\left \langle a^{2} \right \rangle$,$\left \langle a^{4} \right \rangle$,$\left \langle a^{5} \right \rangle$,$\left \langle a^{10} \right \rangle$,$\left \langle a^{20} \right \rangle$

Am I right? What about the generators? 
By the looks of it the subgroups looks like the generators itself.
I'm feeling extremely confused and lost as to how I should determine the generators.

Comment: By definition, $g$ is a generator of the cyclic subgroup $\langle g \rangle$.

Comment: Note, by the way, that $a^{20} = e$.

Comment: @Travis Going by the definition, $a^{k}$ is the generator for $\left \langle a^{k}  \right \rangle $?

Comment: It is *a* generator for $\langle a^k \rangle$---that's the definition of the notation $\langle \,\cdot\, \rangle$. Note that a cyclic group in general has many generators. For example, both $a^5$ and $a^{15} = a^{-5}$ are generators of $\langle a^5 \rangle$, as $(a^{15})^3 = a^5$.